How do computer scientists finds a minimum of a tuple?
In multiobjective optimization, what does it mean to minimize a function of the form $F(a)=(O_1,-O_2,...,O_n)$? I mean, in mathematics, we can order every set by Zorn's lemma but I think we need some kind of criteria how to compare different tuples as in general there is no unique way to order for example complex numbers. The notation appears in the article Direct policy search for robust multi-objective management of deeply
uncertain socio-ecological tipping points.

There is no general way of minimizing a function with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ unless you define an order on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which you can do even without Zorn's Lemma. For instance, the order given by the components (i.e. you sort w.r.t. the first component and if it is equal, you look at the second one, and so on...) is a total order on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Note that Zorn's Lemma instead guarantees you that you can find on every set $X$ an order which makes it well-ordered, i.e. such that every subset of $X$ has a minimum.
Alternatively, you have to define a function which brings your vector to $\mathbb{R}$ and then you can minimize it using the usual total order of $\mathbb{R}$. It can be for instance a norm, a projection, or whatever function you need for your specific purpose.
